# Setting a photo as background in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to upload a photo as a background in p5.js. Unfortunately I become 2 error messages in the console.

```
    p5.js:74522 Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/project/sample.png. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
_main.default.loadImage @ p5.js:74522
setup @ sketch.js:15
_setup @ p5.js:58811
_start @ p5.js:58739
p5 @ p5.js:59080
_globalInit @ p5.js:58340
load (async)
25.../core/main @ p5.js:58353
o @ p5.js:34
(anonymous) @ p5.js:38
16../color/color_conversion @ p5.js:52829
o @ p5.js:34
r @ p5.js:51
(anonymous) @ p5.js:55
(anonymous) @ p5.js:18
(anonymous) @ p5.js:20

p5.js:74522 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at p5._main.default.loadImage (p5.js:74522)
    at setup (sketch.js:15)
    at p5._setup (p5.js:58811)
    at p5._start (p5.js:58739)
    at new p5 (p5.js:59080)
    at _globalInit (p5.js:58340)
```

That's my code:

```
var back;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 600);
  back = loadImage("sample.png");
}

function draw() {
    background(back);
}
```

Where is my mistake and what can I do for the photo to be shown? 
Thank you in advance! Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Have you tried googling your error message? It's telling you that you need to run a server. You can't load local files using the `loadImage()` function.

Comment: Yes, I tried it and I started my local server.

Comment: How are you starting your local server? If you're running a local server, the URL should not start with `file://` and it should not contain the full hard drive path.

Comment: cd path to the folder of the project and then `http-server`. I am loading the photo (`back = loadImage("sample.png");`), there are no message errors anymore, but I still cannot see it in the browser.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] using the [P5.js editor](https://editor.p5js.org/)?

Comment: I solved the problem, in p5js you have to write `loadImage("sample.png")` in `function preload()`. So now it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with loading the background image in the `preload()` function:

```
function preload() {
  back = loadImage("sample.png");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 600);
}

function draw() {
    background(back);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem while making a background image.

I solved this, by running a server in the p5.js project.

I used python HTTP server
The command to start the server in python 3.x as follows.

```
py -m http.server
```

See the demo video on changing background image using a server.

[Bubbles screensaver using p5.js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C52PSTsAoj4&feature=youtu.be)